# How to check value of input is greater than 12 in jquery using if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check value of input is greater than 12 in jquery using if statement

```
 var time = $('#assessTime');
 $(time).keypress(function(){
     debugger;
     if($(this).val() > 12){
     alert("hello");
     }
 });
```

Comment: Now, what goes wrong with the current code?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question. the current code will work fine according to what is asked.

Comment: Your existing code works, but you'll want to use the 'keyup' event rather than 'keypress' (with keypress you're getting the value before the user input, you want the value after the user input.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="number" value="0" />

$('input').on('input', function () {

var value = $(this).val();

  if ((value !== '') && (value.indexOf('.') === -1)) {

    $(this).val(Math.max(Math.min(value, 12), -12));
  }
});
```

It set limitation to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var time = $('#assessTime');
 $(time).keyup(function(){
     debugger;
     if(Number($(this).val()) > 12){
     alert("hello");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Please check the below code to check the given input value is greater than 12.**

**Fix1:**

```
 var time = $('#assessTime');
 $(time).keypress(function(){
     if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 12){
         alert("Yes the given input value is Greater than 12..");
      }
 });
```

**Fix2:**

```
 var time = $('#assessTime');
 $(time).keypress(function(){
     if(Number($(this).val()) > 12){
         alert("Yes the given input value is Greater than 12..");
      }
 });
```

Comment: @Teemu  Yes, You are correct Teemu. in this case we can use Number($(this).val()).
if i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Yep, that or unary plus or parseFloat would do.